# Background image working with SurfaceView

Tags: android, performance, background-image, android-canvas, surfaceview

Working with a SurfaceView to make a 2d game i do not know who to put a background image in it efficiently.
I want to avoid drawing it each frame because it is an static image, any help?

Comment: How about android:background="@drawable/your_image" ?

Comment: SurfaceView is opaque so is it no possible to see behind that unless you set the format of SurfaceHolder in another types but this makes application lose performance even more then drawing the background in canvas each frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SurfaceView's Surface is a single layer.  You can specify a dirty rect to reduce your draw area when you lock the Canvas, but you have to draw everything in the rect every frame -- background and all.

You could use a pair of SurfaceViews, one at the default Z-ordering, one at "media" depth.  Use [SurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay(boolean)) to do that.  The layers will be composited by the system before being rendered.

If you were using OpenGL ES rather than Canvas, it'd generally be more efficient to just redraw the background from a texture each time.  (If [HWC](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html) runs out of overlays, that's essentially what SurfaceFlinger is doing anyway.)

See the "multi-surface test" in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) for an example of using multiple overlapping surfaces.